# MediaPlayer with seekbar Using Handler not working ??

Tags: android

hi i am trying to make a simple media player app including seek bar. the issue is when i am trying to update the seek bar as the it goes on, the song is not running smoothly while the seek bar is updating. i have looked so many links over the internet but cannot resolve my problem. please have a look at my code snippet.

```
paly.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                s_player.start();

                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        start_time = s_player.getCurrentPosition();
                        s_bar.setProgress(start_time);
                    }
                }, 500);

        }
    });
```

Comment: your `Runnable` is called only once so how it is supposed to update as time goes by?

Comment: can you please guide me little more about how this can be done ??